# VB getting garbage textbox output at end of loop

Tags: vb.net

I made a VBA application that pulls from a text file, and goes through a list of servers running the QWINSTA command against them to look for Terminal Services sessions for a particular user, the idea is our helpdesk can type in a username and click a button and it crawls a list of servers, quickly and identifies where someone is logged on.

for some reason at the end of my loop I get some odd output in the textbox it writes to that appears to be the query data, but not in the proper format, repeated several times

here's the code, the "END OF OUTPUT" line was added to the end to determine if the garbage data was before of after this line and it seems to occur before, because this line writes after the loop has been exited.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Creates Thread
    Dim T1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf SessionFinder)

    'Start Thread
    T1.Start()

    LabelStatus.Text = "Running..."

End Sub

'SessionFinder 2.0 - searches for RDP Sessions on terminal servers

Sub SessionFinder()

    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

    ProgressBar1.Value = 0

    'declares variables
    Dim objFSO, objShell, profile, server, oFSO, WSHshell, oTextStream, RemotePC


    'Inputbox that collects username

    profile = TextBoxProfile.Text

    'Creates Class Objects
    objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")


    TextBoxResults.Text = "RDP Sessions for user " & profile & " exists on the following servers" & ControlChars.CrLf
    'TextBoxResults.Text &= "_______________________________________________________________________________" & ControlChars.CrLf
    TextBoxResults.Text &= " " & ControlChars.CrLf

    'open the file system object
    oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    WSHshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    'open the data file
    oTextStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile("phlist.txt")
    'make an array from the data file
    RemotePC = Split(oTextStream.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
    'close the data file
    oTextStream.Close()

    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
    ProgressBar1.Step = 1

    For Each server In RemotePC

        Label8.Text = server

        'The Query is launched
        Dim Query As New Process

        Query.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\windows\system32\qwinsta.exe"
        Query.StartInfo.Arguments = "/server:" & server & " " & profile
        Query.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Query.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Query.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
        Query.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True


        Query.Start()
        Query.WaitForExit(3000)

        If Query.HasExited = False Then
            TextBoxResults.Text &= "_________________________________________________________________" & ControlChars.CrLf
            TextBoxResults.Text &= server & " Not Responding, skipping..."

            Query.Kill()

        Else

            'Do Nothing
        End If


        Dim output As String = Query.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd



        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) Then

            'MsgBox("/server:" & server & " " & profile)
            'MsgBox(output)

            'Results are Echoed to TextboxResults
            TextBoxResults.Text &= "_________________________________________________________________" & ControlChars.CrLf
            TextBoxResults.Text &= server & ControlChars.CrLf
            TextBoxResults.Text &= output

        Else

            'Do nothing

        End If

        output = Nothing

        ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    Next




    LabelStatus.Text = "Complete"

    TextBoxResults.Text &= "_________________________________________________________________" & ControlChars.CrLf
    TextBoxResults.Text &= "END OF OUTPUT"

    ProgressBar1.Value = 100

    Me.BringToFront()

End Sub
```

Here's a sample of what the output is supposed to look like

```
RDP Sessions for user amis5235 exists on the following servers

_________________________________________________________________
XDIS1
SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
ica-tcp#4         amis5235                  6  Active  wdica               
_________________________________________________________________
XAXCL4 Not Responding, skipping...
_________________________________________________________________
XAXCL6 Not Responding, skipping...
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here's what ends up trailing on the end, which I'd like to eliminate

```
_________________________________________________________________

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
>ica-tcp#4         amis5235                  6  Active  wdica               
_________________________________________________________________

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
>ica-tcp#4         amis5235                  6  Active  wdica               
_________________________________________________________________

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
>ica-tcp#4         amis5235                  6  Active  wdica               
_________________________________________________________________

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
>ica-tcp#4         amis5235                  6  Active  wdica               
_________________________________________________________________

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
>ica-tcp#4         amis5235                  6  Active  wdica               
_________________________________________________________________

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
>ica-tcp#4         amis5235                  6  Active  wdica               
_________________________________________________________________

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
>ica-tcp#4         amis5235                  6  Active  wdica               
_________________________________________________________________

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
>ica-tcp#4         amis5235                  6  Active  wdica               
_________________________________________________________________
END OF OUTPUT
```

Comment: It seems that RemotePC array has duplicates. Try MsgBox RemotePC.Count before the For Loop. Does it represent the right number of servers?

Comment: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` means "I like getting garbage, bring it on!"

Comment: you pointed me in the direction that brought about an answer and I'm thankful for that, your comment about the duplicates caused me to double check my text file, it seems there were a number of carriage returns after the last entry, looks like it was trying to process the empty lines, cleaning up the text file, fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the thread is being terminated. Try this:

```
Dim T1 As System.Threading.Thread;

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Creates Thread
    T1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf SessionFinder)

    'Start Thread
    T1.Start()

    LabelStatus.Text = "Running..."

End Sub
```

Note: this is just an example not production code ;)

Comment: tried your change, doesn't seem to make a difference, don't know if it matters, but the "ping" was added as a way to timeout the command, otherwise if one of the servers in the list is down, it takes a VERY LONG time for the command to timeout and the loop to advance on it's own, defeating the purpose of a quick tool. I can understand the command being terminated prematurely have an odd output effect, just don't know why, or if there is a better way to go about polling the servers prior to trying to query them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm almost laughing right now, Ahmad's comment prompted me to check my text file I was reading from, looking at the end of the file there were a number of empty carriage returns, seems like my application was trying to process the empty lines as servers, which now makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the sounding board everyone, just what I needed.